# delete image from folder after deleting the record containing that image from databse

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table in my database containing two columns ID and Image.
when inserting my image into database i use the following code.

```
    <pre lang='cs'>

       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO info(ID,Img_Image) VALUES(@ID,@Img_image));
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtID.Text);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", test_image);
    </pre>
```

...
That test_image loads the Image from a path i.e. (C:\foldername).

Now my problem is that when i delete a specific record...the corresponding Image in the folder should get deleted.

P.S.: i am using the standard SQL delete code for deleting a record.

Comment: `test_image` contains the path, or some image data?

Answer (score 3):

After deleting the record from table you can delete the physical file by using System.IO.File.Delete or using FileInfo

```
string filePath = "C:\test.txt";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
if (file.Exists)
{
   file.Delete();
}
```

Comment: I would just add it is better to use 
string filePath = Server.MapPath("C:\test.txt");

Answer (score 0):

Delete Your Physical file - works 100%

```
File.Delete(Server.MapPath("../App_Themes/UPLOADS/banner_img/5.jpg"));

//if some error occurs like , don't have rights 

//uncheck readonly option in folder properties
```